# Why is Google token auth API always returning Bad Request error?

Tags: c#, google-oauth

I am following the official Google Docs to establish a web request to let users access my WebApp via Google Authentication.

I am stuck at the second step: retrieving the authentication token after getting the "code" parameter from the first step.

URI1 (used to obtain "code" parameter): https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
URI2 (the one I am using in this step): https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

This is my implementation:

```cs
var requestCode = Request.Query["code"].ToString();

var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", _googleSettings.ClientId),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", _googleSettings.ClientSecret),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", _googleSettings.RedirectUris[1]),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", requestCode),
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_googleSettings.TokenUri, content);
```

The response is always not successful and returns Error 400 Bad Request.

I searched and watched many tutorials and none of them worked.

Following there is the response I get.

```
    {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Wed, 09 Aug 2023 20:25:03 GMT
  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  Pragma: no-cache
  Vary: X-Origin
  Vary: Referer
  Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
  Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
  X-XSS-Protection: 0
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000
  Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
  Accept-Ranges: none
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}
```

**EDIT: I found the solution**

I configured two callback URIs in the Google App but due to some unknown reasons, Google didn't accept the second in the list (it gave Bad Request error). Fortunately, as a last chance, I tried using the first redirect URI registered and it worked.

Comment: any special reason you don't want to use the client library?

Comment: What type of web app is this asp .net?

Comment: This is AspNetBoilerplate MVC application, what do you mean for client library?

Answer (score 1):

The format of the body is wrong it needs to be UrlEncode

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Comment: I tried your method and it didn't work, it gives 400 Bad Request message. Isn't FormUrlEncodedContent class supposed to do what you said? I tried also using the method explained in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926053/google-oauth2-token-bad-request and didn't work too.

Comment: did you remove all the stuff from encodedUrl and reformat the post body.  I have a sample for C# floating around I will see if i can find it in the moring

Answer (score 0):

Two things I would look at here:

First: the request parameters go in the body, not as query string parameters. I'm not certain that's causing the error though because you are sending them both as part of the body and as query string parameters. From [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_3):

> To exchange an authorization code for an access token, call the https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token endpoint and set the following parameters:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> POST /token HTTP/1.1
> Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
> client_id=your_client_id&
> client_secret=your_client_secret&
> redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&
> grant_type=authorization_code
> ```

Which means that your code should look like this:

```cs
var requestCode = Request.Query["code"].ToString();

var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "MY_CLIENT_ID"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "MY_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:PORT/Account/ExternalLoginCallback"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", requestCode),
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", content);
```

The second thing you need to confirm is that your `redirect_uri` is (from [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_3) again):

> One of the redirect URIs listed for your project in the API Console Credentials page for the given client_id.

To list redirect URIs for your `client_id` see step 4 in [Create Authorization Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingcred)

Comment: My code exactly looks like that and redirect utis are all listed in the google app configuration.

Comment: It didn't look like that when you first posted the question though. You were adding the parameters as query string parameters as well as on the body.

Comment: Yes because that was the result of my first edit due to the hint of the other comment but unfortunately it didn't work, so I came back to the previous block of code replacing stirngs with parameters stored in appsettings.json.

Comment: Apart from a 400 Bad Request, can you inspect the response for details. You'll usually get some details hinting as what is wrong in the request.

Comment: I inspected the response deeply, I couldn't find any detail regarding the error.

Comment: Posted the response in the edit

Comment: Just checking the obvious, but you do get a code right? I mean, have you checked that `requestCode` is not empty?

Comment: I just solved. I'm posting the edit.